# Permission Denied after upgrade to 22.04.1

Tags: server, upgrade, permissions, 22.04

After upgrading from 20.04 (a server install) I seem to have permission issues. When using SSH to connect it successfully logs in, but I then get:

```
/bin/bash: Permission denied
```

Trying from the tty, it logs in and logs immediately out - no doubt because of the permission denied.

To be able to get access, I've had to enable the root account (boot from usb, set password).

/bin is a symlink to usr/bin. usr has permissions 755, as does usr/bin, and all the files beneath that are at least 755, so it's not a file or directory permissions error.

Is there another permissions mechanism that has been added in 22.04 that I have missed, or is there something else that could have messed up during the upgrade?
Thanks.

Comment: What does `stat /bin/bash` output?

Comment: @ArturMeinild

    File: /bin/bash
      Size: 1396520         Blocks: 2728       IO Block: 4096   regular file
    Device: 812h/2066d      Inode: 797886      Links: 1
    Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
    Access: 2022-09-18 16:29:04.034856383 +0100
    Modify: 2022-01-06 16:23:33.000000000 +0000
    Change: 2022-09-18 16:27:51.555925785 +0100
    Birth: 2022-09-18 16:27:51.551925844 +0100

Answer (score 0):

The problem extended to pretty much every application that was attempted to be run as another user.

Browsing through usr, lib etc. the lib64 directory did not have any "other" rights (unlike every other directory). chmod o+rx seems to have fixed the issue now.